# My android app crashes on launch, and the stack trace doesn't show anything

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I'm new to android development, and I'm trying to build a simple note taking app.

I've decided to use Realm instead of SQLite, but I couldn't figure out how to connect everything on the DB to my RecyclerView, so I found an example on their GitHub about creating Adapters for RecyclerViews that display data from a Realm DB.

I copied most of the code and edited it to suit my app, but now it crashes on launch, and I have no idea what's causing it because the stack trace doesn't show anything.

I've uploaded the app to [this repo](https://github.com/odinuts/Memo) on GitHub for people to check it out and tell me what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in the logs. Maybe you have a filter applied in the view?

The issue is that you are initializing Realm incorrectly.

```
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.odinuts.memo.app.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5364)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:399)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:394)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.odinuts.memo.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:13)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5361)
03-31 15:56:54.403  8728  8728 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
```

Edit: In Android Studio check your `Android Monitor` tab and make sure the following filters are correct

```
1) Process (this should be your app
2) Regex/selection (select your app, or no filters) 
3) Log level (debug, info, error, etc)
4) Device (in case you have several)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if I have a filter? I don't think I do

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just have to add `Realm.init(this);` before the RealmConfiguration